# Postfix and Dovecot - No encryption on SMTP

Tags: postfix, smtp, configuration, dovecot

Currently I'm working on my very own mail server but as for now I can't get SMTP up correctly.
I use Dovecot with postfix.
When I try to add my server to my mail client it tells me:

[Outgoing: SMTP (my servers address):587, No SSL, Authentification: Normal password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7gxb.png)

I don't know why I get this result since I thought I had everything set up.

I have no experience with postfix until today so I have no idea what's missing or wrong.

System: fresh Debian 10 x64,
installed postfix, dovecot-core, dovecot-imapd and dovecot-pop3d.

Here is my postfix main.cf: https://pastebin.com/S17jWDQd
Here is my postfix master.cf: https://pastebin.com/W0nynZG6
Here is my dovecot.conf: https://pastebin.com/tMD90Znn

Most of these contents are copied from an iRedMail installation so I think I missed something while copying and modifying for my own use.

Here are my mail logs:

```
root@bgrsld-mail0:~# tail /var/log/mail.info
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: warning: unsupported dictionary type: pcre (/usr/lib/postfix/postfix-pcre.so: No such file or directory)
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: connect from unknown[192.168.2.110]
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: warning: pcre:/etc/postfix/command_filter.pcre is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: warning: pcre:/etc/postfix/command_filter.pcre lookup error for "EHLO we-guess.mozilla.org"
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: NOQUEUE: reject: CONNECT from unknown[192.168.2.110]: 421 4.3.0 bgrsld-mail0.intern.bdevgw.de Server local data error
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.2.110] commands=0/0
Jul 17 17:56:27 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/anvil[7456]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (submission:192.168.2.110) at Jul 17 17:53:07
Jul 17 17:56:27 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/anvil[7456]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (submission:192.168.2.110) at Jul 17 17:53:07
Jul 17 17:56:27 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/anvil[7456]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Jul 17 17:53:07
root@bgrsld-mail0:~# tail /var/log/mail.err
Jul 17 17:33:46 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7335]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jul 17 17:36:31 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7444]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jul 17 17:36:31 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7444]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jul 17 17:36:31 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7444]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jul 17 17:36:31 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7451]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jul 17 17:36:31 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7451]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jul 17 17:36:31 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7451]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
root@bgrsld-mail0:~# tail /var/log/mail.warn
Jul 17 17:36:31 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7451]: warning: pcre:/etc/postfix/command_filter.pcre lookup error for "EHLO we-guess.mozilla.org"
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: warning: unsupported dictionary type: pcre (/usr/lib/postfix/postfix-pcre.so: No such file or directory)
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: warning: unsupported dictionary type: pcre (/usr/lib/postfix/postfix-pcre.so: No such file or directory)
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: warning: unsupported dictionary type: pcre (/usr/lib/postfix/postfix-pcre.so: No such file or directory)
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: error: unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: warning: pcre:/etc/postfix/command_filter.pcre is unavailable. unsupported dictionary type: pcre
Jul 17 17:53:07 bgrsld-mail0 postfix/submission/smtpd[7454]: warning: pcre:/etc/postfix/command_filter.pcre lookup error for "EHLO we-guess.mozilla.org"
```

Comment: What is your Linux distribution? How did you install Postfix?

Comment: Systeminformation added above the config files. Installed via apt.

Comment: The Postfix `main.cf` tells nothing about how *submission* is configured, as it's configured in the `master.cf`.

Comment: added master.cf to post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious fix for the error shown is to install the `postfix-pcre` package to provide that capability. The Mozilla autodetection should then be able to talk to Postfix.

Comment: ok that fixed it. Thanks. Didn't knew what that is and since it's also listed as "warn" I didn't thought it would really matter to work on this [facepalm]